# Setup DSL connection via netplan?

Tags: netplan, dsl, adsl

I haven't seen any options to setup up DSL connection in `/etc/netplan`?  
I know it's possible via **pppoeconf**, but I'm not sure how to modify the `dsl-provider` file/name (I need to setup for 2 different providers), so that it will still use it on boot time.

Answer (score 1):

netplan does not directly support PPPoE connections today (netplan 0.105).  There are two possible solutions using the supported tools in Ubuntu main.

- I use a `networkd-dispatcher` script in `/etc/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d` which starts the ppp connection whenever the ethernet device comes up:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  set -e

  if [ "$IFACE" != wan ]; then
          exit 0
  fi

  pppd call centurylink

  sleep 5

  ip route change default dev ppp0 advmss 1482
  ```

  I then have an additional script linked from each of `/etc/networkd-dispatcher/{degraded,dormant,no-carrier,off}.d/` which stops it when it goes down:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  set -e

  if [ "$IFACE" != wan ]; then
          exit 0
  fi

  if [ -e /run/ppp-centurylink.pid ]; then
          pid=$(cat /run/ppp-centurylink.pid)
          kill "$pid"
  fi
  ```

  This approach connects the ppp configuration you have created (via `pppoeconf` or other means) to `networkd`.
- You can configure your PPPoE connection directly in `NetworkManager`.

Comment: Thanks @slangsek, When I ran pppoeconf it will create 2 files in `/etc/ppp/peers`, so I was able to check, update config there in the dsl-provider file, and it has a full setup.  I didn't try with networkd-dispacher, not sure if any better.  It's too bad netplan doesn't have that option

Comment: `pppoeconf` generates the config for ppp, but does not address the question of how you manage the connection.  You can do it manually from the commandline, but if you want the connection to start automatically and stay up, interfacing with either networkd-dispatcher or NetworkManager is still a good idea.